# Removing z-index from this transition code

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, z-index

How would I go about restructuring the code so that z-index isn’t needed on the transition?

**Without** z-index:
https://jsfiddle.net/Legcb42d/

```
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container1.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.door-left,
.door-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 8s;
}

.door-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
}

.door-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
}

.container1.slide .door-left {
  left: -50%;
}

.container1.slide .door-right {
  left: 100%;
}

<div class="container1 ">
<div class="door-left"></div>
<div class="door-right"></div>

(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
    document.querySelector(".container1").classList.add('slide');
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    const thewrap = cover.parentNode.querySelector(".container");
    hide(cover);
    show(thewrap);
  }
  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

**It's not supposed to look like this.**

**Without** z-index:
https://jsfiddle.net/Legcb42d/

[image]

**This is how it should look.**

**With** z-index:
https://jsfiddle.net/rspxkyoL/

[image]

Comment: Could you describe why you don't want to use z-index? If you really can't then you'll have to restructure your code - are you allowed to do that?

Comment: Yes I am allowed to restructure the code. How would I do that ?

Comment: How would I restructure the code so that z-index isn't needed?

Comment: Are you able to help me with this?

Comment: I don't want to use z-index because I removed it from the rest of the code and now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to remove this one.

Comment: Try restructuring the HTML so that the things you want to be on top are painted after the other stuff (the doors and jacketa after the other things). Please though explain why z-index isn't allowed as it would be the natural solution.

Comment: Everything I tried in the HTML did not work. Were you able to figure it out? I tried every different combination.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `z-index`? If you are thinking that the play button will be hidden if you increase it for doors then you can also increase the play button's z-index.

Add z-index for

```css
.door-left,
.door-right {
   ...
   z-index: 1;
}

.jacketa {
   ...
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL57q0xd/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the use of z-index? Is it possible?

Comment: @MandyEvans Answer Updated

Comment: @MandyEvans As you have asked for a solution without `z-index`, You also have to adjust CSS too.

Comment: There is something that is not working correctly. Look... https://jsfiddle.net/6xpu1rem/ How do I fix that? Something is broken.

Comment: You have to make adjustments to your code. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/6xpu1rem/ Do you see what needs to be fixed/adjusted? The way you have it set up now, it doesn't work, it's not correct.

Comment: The height of the sliding door transition does not go all the way down the entire page. Also, the transition effect isn't working properly, which you can see in the jsfiddle I provided. https://jsfiddle.net/6xpu1rem/

Comment: Look, as described above. https://i.imgur.com/thGGcPh.png Do you see how it does not go down the entire page? That needs to be fixed.

Comment: @MandyEvans As the door `div`s are moved outside the container we again need to wrap whole elements into another div to stop overflow of doors, I have updated answer and fiddle, See if it helps.

Comment: Mine Before: https://jsfiddle.net/Legcb42d/ Yours, After: https://jsfiddle.net/m4vzyp9o/

Still not working. Do you see the difference between those both?

Comment: I am able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page on my code.  https://jsfiddle.net/Legcb42d/ ---- On your code: https://jsfiddle.net/m4vzyp9o/ I am not able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234601/discussion-between-sameer-and-mandy-evans).